# VPS inaccessible after a few seconds of boot

Tags: debian, vps

I got a debian VPS last day and installed on it a few things (nodejs, nginx, redis) and as of last night it's mostly inaccessible by ping, after each reboot it works for a few seconds and then goes to blackout, I have no idea what happens. With each reboot I have a few seconds to ssh to it and do a command or two.

I know this is a very vague question, but it's because I don't know what I'm looking for. If you have any idea of what might be the cause, please say.

UPDATE:

It was a network issue after all, after restarting networking (eth0) daemon for a few seconds everything is fine, but after that I can't even ping the gateway!
iptables are empty, no policy is added.

Comment: Use the virtual console to log in and diagnose the issue. If you have a VPS that doesn't provide one, get rid of it and get another one that does..

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a firewall issue. I would try:

Create file:
/root/stop.fw

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "Stopping firewall and allowing everyone..."
iptables -F
iptables -X
iptables -t nat -F
iptables -t nat -X
iptables -t mangle -F
iptables -t mangle -X
iptables -P INPUT ACCEPT
iptables -P FORWARD ACCEPT
iptables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT
```

then:

```
$ sudo chmod +x /root/stop.fw
$ sudo /root/stop.fw
$ sudo iptables -L
```

ALSO TRY:

/etc/ssh/sshd_config:

SET:

```
TCPKeepAlive yes
ClientAliveInterval 30
ClientAliveCountMax 999999
```

restart SSHd

Comment: nmap says Note: Host seems down, this is why I didn't think of it as a network issue. Any idea?